# How to skip iterations in a for loop in PHP?

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a list of options (booked seats) from which I want to exclude certain values (e.g., 3, 4, 8 and 19). The code I have for constructing the list is:

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=27; $i++)
  {
    echo "<option value=$i>$i</option>";
  }
?>
```

How do I exclude 3, 4, 8 and 19 from the list?

Comment: I'm guessing the -1 vote is due to the bluntness of the post.  I understood what andesign was asking.

Comment: @MrVimes - I understood it too. In fact the question is quite clear and has a code snippet. This puts it head and shoulder above many other questions. The general wording and title could be improved, but it's a great question.

Comment: yes, it simple. but I dont understand how to make the code. thank you

Comment: Because i saw your question the other day and know what you are working on here I feel compelled to say youre going about this the wrong way. You should be using an array of open seats NOT explicitly looping over a set number of seats in order. What if you get new buses that have 30 seats? What if you have to refer to buses by some special ticketing string instead of number?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `continue` to skip the current iteration of a loop.

```
$exclude = array(3, 4, 8, 19);

for ($i=1; $i<=27; $i++)
{
    if (in_array($i, $exclude)) continue;
    echo "<option value=$i>$i</option>";
}
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php).

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel I'd say it is more of a place for people to get their programming related questions answered. Every great programmer had to start somewhere too.

Comment: @andesign thank you for your support. You are the perfect example of what I am talking about. You've been told you are doing wrong way, but you prefer not to listen. But just copy-paste. Nuff said.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel I disagree. I signed up to this site knowing a great deal less than I do know (just look at some of my early questions). The majority of that learning (somewhere around 80%) was done by using Stack Overflow.

Comment: I agree with @alex. I gained very good knowledge after to join SO. It's a great site.

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME! @YCS for someone with such high rep, you are very nasty toward this site and it's users....