# Display specific numbers in php for

Tags: php

I am creating a form that includes a dropdown menu with numbers 1-12 as an option to choose. I want to display only the numbers 1-9 and 11, 12. All of them except the number 10 that is not wanted.

Here is the code that i have created.

```
<select id="idiom" name="idiom">
          <?php for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option> 
          <?php } ?>
                                    </select>
```

I have read but i cant understand that there is a php unset rule that can make the number 10 to not display. But i don't know how i can create the function to do this.

Comment: just use `if($i != 10){ `

Comment: You could just put an if condition inside your for loop.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597461/how-to-skip-iterations-in-a-for-loop-in-php

Answer (score 3):

A simple conditional check will let you skip the 10 using [continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php).

```
<select id="idiom" name="idiom">
    <?php 
        for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) { 
            if($i === 10) {
              continue; //skip to next
            }
    ?>             
        <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option> 
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

The OP sounded like they were interested in PHP's `unset()` function. To use this, you might combine it with `range()` something like this:

```
$range = range(1, 12);
unset($range[9]); // Where '9' is the key to the '10' value
<select id="idiom" name="idiom">
  <?php foreach($range as $num) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $num;?>"><?php echo $num;?></option> 
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```